# User enters what the file name is they want to read in?

Tags: java

For the purpose of this class task, we have been asked to make a program that uses the File Class(I know input stream is much better) but yeah, we have to ask the user to input the name of the .txt file.

```
public class input {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    int lineCount = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;


    System.out.println("Please type the file you want to read in: ");
    name = s.next();

    File input = new File("C:\\Users\\Ceri\\workspace1\\inputoutput\\src\\inputoutput\\lab1task3.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
```

How would I  get

```
 File input = new File(...);
```

to search for the file as just typing 'lab1task3' doesn't work.

edit: error -

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \lab1task3.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
at inputoutput.input.main(input.java:19)
```

Comment: Do you want to get the `File` inside a given folder? Or do you want to search your whole file system?

Comment: What error do you get? And should the app search for the file or just open it?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock yeah in a given folder or relative folders.

Comment: What about `File input = new File(name + ".txt");`

Comment: If the file you are looking for is outside of the program directory, it will not be found UNLESS the FULL FILE PATH is specified. Make sure you have the file in the directory, or specify the full and exact file path.

Comment: @EvanBechtol the .txt file is in the exact same folder as the class. still says cannot be found hmm.

Comment: @ceriwestcott - What is the exact error you are getting when you say that it cannot be found?

Comment: @ceriWestcott Have you tried using s.nextLine();   Instead of s.next()?

Comment: @Ascalonian updated the post with the error

Comment: Thanks! Check out what @EvanBechtol suggested too :-)

Comment: @EvanBechtol I still get the same error :(

Comment: @ceriWestcott - I say you just use a `JFileChooser` and make them pick the file haha

Comment: @Ascalonian sadly the lab task has to be performed with User input.

Comment: What about this? `String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir"); String filePath = workingDirectory + File.separator + name;`

Answer (score 1):

Scanner can't read in files that way, you need to store it as a file first!
If you put this inside of a try-catch block, you can ensure that the program won't break if a file isn't found. I would suggest wrapping it in a do-while/while loop (depending on structure), with the end condition being that the file is found.

I changed your main method to this and it compiles correctly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please type the file you want to read in: ");
    String fname = sc.nextLine();

    File file = new File (fname);
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To search for a file inside a specific folder, you could just iterate over the files inside the given folder via:

```
File givenFolder = new File(...);
String fileName = (...);
File toSearch = findFile(givenFolder, fileName);
```

Where the function **findFile(File folder, String fileName)** would iterate over the files in the **givenFolder** and try to find the file. It could look like this:

```
public File findFile(File givenFolder, String fileName)
{
   List<File> files = getFiles();
   for(File f : files)
   {
     if(f.getName().equals(fileName))
     {
       return f;
     }
   }
   return null;
}
```

The function **getFiles** is just iterating over all files in the given folder and calls it self when finding a folder:

```
public List<File> getFiles(File givenFolder)
{
  List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
  for(File f : givenFolder.listFiles())
  {
    if(f.isDirectory())
    {
       files.addAll(getFiles(f));
    }
    else
    {
       files.add(f);
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you :) If you want to know more about what happens here exactly feel free to ask :)